# PHP: Can't connect to francium diffsocket

Tags: phpwebsocket

I am developing a simple group chat using websocket on xampp 7.0.9, in windows. Here is my code:

run-server.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$DS = new Fr\DiffSocket(array(
   "server" => array(
   "host" => "127.0.0.1",
   "port" => "8000"
   )
));
$DS->addService("hello", __DIR__ . "/Hello.php");
$DS->run();
```

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="http://lab.subinsb.com/projects/jquery/core/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            window.ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/?service=hello");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Hello.php

```
<?php
namespace Fr\DiffSocket\Service;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Hello implements MessageComponentInterface {

  public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn){
    echo "New Connection - " . $conn->resourceId;
  }

  public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn){}
  public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, $error){}

  public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $message){
    $conn->send("Hello");
  }

}
?>
```

run-server.php starts well, but when I connect by running index.php, I get the following JavaScript error:

```
(index):6 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/?service=hello' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

And this in the run-server.php

> Server started on 127.0.0.1:8000 
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$request in E:\Projects\Installed\xmpp\htdocs\soc\server\vendor\francium\diffsocket\src\DiffSocket\Server.php on line 80
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getQuery() on null in E:\Projects\Installed\xmpp\htdocs\soc\server\vendor\francium\diffsocket\src\DiffSocket\Server.php:80 Stack trace: #0 E:\Projects\Installed\xmpp\htdocs\soc\server\vendor\francium\diffsocket\src\DiffSocket\Server.php(25): Fr\DiffSocket\Server->getService(Object(Ratchet\WebSocket\WsConnection)) #1 E:\Projects\Installed\xmpp\htdocs\soc\server\vendor\cboden\ratchet\src\Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer.php(142): Fr\DiffSocket\Server->onOpen(Object(Ratchet\WebSocket\WsConnection)) #2 E:\Projects\Installed\xmpp\htdocs\soc\server\vendor\cboden\ratchet\src\Ratchet\Http\HttpServer.php(51): Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer->onOpen(Object(Ratchet\Server\IoConnection), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) #3 E:\Projects\Installed\xmpp\htdocs\soc\server\vendor\cboden\ratchet\src\Ratchet\Server\IoServer.php(112): Ratchet\Http\HttpServer->onMessage(Object(Ratchet\Server\IoConnection), 'GET /?service=h...') #4 E:\Projects\Installed\xmpp\htdocs\soc\server\vendor\cboden\ratchet\src in E:\Projects\Installed\xmpp\htdocs\soc\server\vendor\francium\diffsocket\src\DiffSocket\Server.php on line 80

Can anyone help please. Thanks.